# Legendary Bear: Died during fight, can't find him anymore

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I just got killed by the bear in the early hunt mission. I respawned and went to look for the bear, but it wasn't there. I searched the whole are with hunting skills, but didn't find it. Any idea, how I can find him again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Same thing happened to me, what I did was ride a decent bit away and set up camp. Slept until the next morning then rode back up towards the icon. When I did that a notification popped up in the top-left part of my screen saying I was in the a legendary animal's territory. Seems like if that notification doesn't pop up it won't spawn the bear so make sure it does before you spend any more time looking for it. Took me awhile to figure that out, hope it helps.

Comment: I think that when I died during this and went back, I did get a notification telling me that it wouldn't be back for a while.

Answer (score -2):

Press up on the d-pad. Select the task you wish to replay from there.